# How to set pixels of point A (x, y) at point A (x, y2) to 1?

Tags: matlab

How to say that the pixels of point A (x, y) at point A (x, y2) are equal to 1? (At first this points equal to 0 and for example there are 5 points between them)

```
            A(x,y):1:A(x,y2)=1;
```

Is it right?

Comment: What do you mean "say"? you mean you want to make them 1?

Comment: Oh yes sorry for my language

Comment: And how do you define the pixels in the middle? I mean, if `x=1,y=1` and `x2=3,y2=3` what are the values in the middle? you want to make the whole square 1 or just the line between the 2?

Comment: No just the line between the 2 points

Comment: So which points should be set up in the case of `x=1,y=1` `x2=3,y2=4`. Because technically, there is none (no integer valued, at least)

Comment: Sorry I do a mistake the points are in the same 'line' so same 'x' and for example if we have A(1,1) and A(1,5) I would like transform A(1,2), A(1,3) et A(1,4) from 0 to 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MATLAB's matrix indexing tools:

`A(x,y1:y2)=1`